# What issues can rise from web gui config changes then making other changes from the CLI?

Tags: cisco, networking, cisco-catalyst, interface, cli

I'm using a 9200L Cisco switch

If I make changes in the CLI, then I make changes in the Web interface and vice versa.

Will there be issues down the road with the config file getting corrupt or security issues related to using both methods?

If I start in the CLI or Web interface, is it best to stick to one mode of changing the config?

I could not find anything to help answer this nuanced question online.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's less confusing for the switch than it might be for you. Basically, the web GUI just translates changes to console commands, practically it's pretty much all the same.

You may get unwanted results if you load the GUI, but continue making changes on the console - not yet reflected in the already loaded GUI - and then change settings from the GUI. The previous changes on the console may get lost in some scenarios. So, skipping back and forth quickly might not be a very good idea.

Most likely you will find that the web GUI is good for first steps, getting a quick visual impression on device state and configuration, and not too much else. Seasoned professionals tend to stick to the console as it's more powerful. It's also quite common to deactivate the GUI entirely to save resources and to close a potential attack vector.

Answer (score 1):

As Zak has already said, the GUI's just generate CLI commands. I don't know if the IOS GUI's have an option to show those commands, but the firewall (PDM/ASDM) do.

Mixing the two *at the same time* is not recommended. The GUI loads the running config at startup and may not notice anything else modifying the configuration. That also applies to multiple GUI sessions. (PDM and ASDM do detect CLI changes and ask to reload the config.)

Comment: Is there a Refresh button in the GUI? That would presumably suffice if you make changes in the CLI during a GUI session.